# Is there any alternative for SqoopOptions class

Tags: java, hadoop, hdfs, sqoop, cloudera-cdh

I am trying to import data from **MySQL** to **Hive** using Java code using `SqoopOptions` class, but it says this class(`com.cloudera.sqoop.SqoopOptions`) is deprecated, [Class SqoopOptions](http://search-hadoop.com/jd/sqoop/com/cloudera/sqoop/SqoopOptions.html). I google out alternative for this but not found anything, Can anyone suggest me what is the alternative to do this. I want to use the sqoop command through my java program.

Answer (score 2):

When Sqoop entered Apache, a lot of the `com.cloudera.sqoop.*` code has been renamed/migrated to `org.apache.sqoop.*`. The class you are looking for is `org.apache.sqoop.SqoopOptions` I believe.

I highly recommend not using Sqoop from a Java program. Instead, try **Sqoop2** for that. I believe you can import into HDFS using the Kite connector in Avro or Parquet formats. Then you should be able to load that data into Hive.

Comment: Yes I was looking for the `org.apache.sqoop.SqoopOptions`, Thanks for reply I get new idea, it will help me lot

Comment: `com.cloudera.sqoop.SqoopOptions` seems to have been "prematurely deprecated", as some functionality of sqoop (e.g. tool classes such as EvalSqlTool) still require it, and do not work with `org.apache.sqoop.SqoopOptions`. Gee, thanks Sqoop for forcing me to see deprecation warnings every time I compile.

Answer (score 1):

One option is you can execute your sqoop import command using [sshxcute](https://code.google.com/p/sshxcute/)

Following is the snippet that you can use

```
import net.neoremind.sshxcute.core.ConnBean;
import net.neoremind.sshxcute.core.Result;
import net.neoremind.sshxcute.core.SSHExec;
import net.neoremind.sshxcute.task.CustomTask;
import net.neoremind.sshxcute.task.impl.ExecCommand;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    ConnBean connBean = new ConnBean("<SYSTEM_IP>", "<USERNAME>","<PASSWORD>");

    SSHExec sshExec = SSHExec.getInstance(connBean); 

    StringBuilder sqoopImportCommand = new StringBuilder("sqoop import --connect jdbc:mysql://<IP_ADDRESS>:<PORT>/<DATABASE> ")
            .append("--username <USERNAME> --password <PASSWORD> --table <TABLE_NAME> --target-dir <HDFS_PATH>");

    try {
        sshExec.connect();

        CustomTask sqoopImportTask = new ExecCommand(sqoopImportCommand.toString());
        Result crres = sshExec.exec(sqoopImportTask);

        if(crres.isSuccess){
            System.out.println("Data imported successfully");
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO: handle exception
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        sshExec.disconnect();
    }
}
```

Comment: if the another system is any machine which we dont have the public key, then is it possible to connect using sshxcute. I have doubt will it work for remote machine?

Comment: As per sshxcute documentations, if your remote system has **open SSH connection with credentials enabled** then you can use sshxcute to connect to your remote system

Comment: yes, exactly, but in my scenario I am working on web based data migration tool which can access from any where. so it is not possible to take credential from each system. then what should I use?

Comment: here you need the credentials of the system in which you want to run the import job not the user system who is running your application. in this case you need the credentials of your remote system in which you have hadoop & sqoop installed which will run sqoop import job and push the data into HDFS

Comment: Here **ConnBean** refers to your remote system in which u have hadoop & sqoop and on this system it will run the sqoop import job when you connect and execute